# Can't connect to mysql after managing systemctl (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock')

Tags: centos, mysql, systemctl

I needed to run a program (just a compiled c++ program, not script, i.e., like `/var/programname`) on startup on CentOS 7.

I followed this guide https://www.howtogeek.com/687970/how-to-run-a-linux-program-at-startup-with-systemd/

Rebooted via `reboot` command, checked if my program is running via `ps aux`, it is.

But now, I can't connect to mysql database (maybe there are other problems). I have phpMyAdmin, it running through browser, but when I try to login it throws:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

Running `mysql -u root -p` command, after input root password throws:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Have I just deleted databases?(

In `/etc/init.d/` currently there are `asterisk  functions  netconsole  network  README`, no `mysql` or `mysqld` folder.

Comment: first, is your mysql daemon running ? (when you do a "systemctl status mysqld.service" or "service mysqld status", what do you get ?)

Comment: @olivierg, I found solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that `mariadb` was not enabled in `systemctl`, i.e. it was not on startup, and hence was not running.

So I ran

`systemctl enable mariadb.service`, as far as remember (I have done it yesterday)

And rebooted the server, now it run on startup.

---

As for my program, I need to run on startup, I removed it from `systemctl`, and going to use `crontab` for that.